# How to count number of distinct values containing specific text

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm not sure if I've phrased that question well so I'll elaborate.

I have 160 lines of file numbers, many of which are duplicates.  In each file number there is a value that determines the year the file was created e.g. /11 or /12 etc.

I've seen on here how you can find the number of distinct entries in a series (in this case it's 63 distinct file numbers), so now I'd like to take it a step further and see how many distinct entries contain "/11", or "/12" etc...

What I'm hoping is that I can have a separate formula for each year that will analyse the 160 cells and tell me that there are, say, 20 unique cells that contain the text "/11".  Then the next formula will tell me that there are 25 unique lells that contain the text "/12" and so on.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Can you add a little more detail, like samples of the entries.  Have you looked at filtering?

Comment: I believe this answer, on StackOverflow, should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15945052/4497791

Answer (score 1):

If you have data in `A1:A160` try this formula to find the number of `different` entries which contain `"/11"`

`=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("/11",A1:A160))/COUNTIF(A1:A160,A1:A160&""))`

Comment: Why can't I enter "/11" in a cell??  *Without the double-quotes??*

Comment: I think it interprets the / as some sort of command - you can stop that - see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/831237, or try entering with a preceding apostrophe like '/11